# How to ad export csv, excel button on vuetify data table?

Tags: vue.js, export, vuetify.js, export-csv, v-data-table

I am new for vuetify and faced problem with exporting my v-data-table to excel, csv format. How can i do it. Any suggestion or reccomondation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `vue-json-to-csv` to export the table data to a `csv` file:

```
<vue-json-to-csv
     :json-data="yourList"
     :csv-title="'fileName'"
>
     <v-btn color="success" class="mr-6">
          Export <i class="mdi mdi-export-variant" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </v-btn>
</vue-json-to-csv>
```

Make sure to pass `yourList` as the data and `fileName` as the desired outputted file name.

Here is the link for more details:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-to-csv